# Format String Output Variable Java

Tags: java, string, exception, format

I am trying to create my output to look like a table in Java. Is it possible to create a standard format that I use for all my output? So far I have?

```
String format = String.format("%-3s%-3s\n");

System.out.printf(format, "foo", "bar");
```

When I am currently trying this with different input and creating my format for use within a for loop I am getting an error saying:

Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%-3s'

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you think `String format = String.format("%-3s%-3s\n");` should do and why do you think so?

Comment: Make `String format = String.format("%-3s%-3s\n");` to be more like `String format = "%-3s%-3s\n";`, basically you're asking `String` to `format` (nothing) to using the specified format, when you just want to make the base format and not apply iy

Comment: @Pshemo I thought 'String format = String.format("%-3s%-3s\n");'  would set a format to be used so when I call it again at 'System.out.printf(format, "foo", "bar");' it would use the same format but with the input i've given.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I realise what I've done now. It makes a lot of sense when I see what was wrong. Thank you!